# Поиск нескольких слов в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно определить несколько слов для поиска в строке? Сейчас находит не точно слово, а даже если есть его часть. Например hellos он найдет, хотя есть только hello.

```js
function validateText(){
  var pattern = /hello|hi/;
    var content = $('.validateText').val().toLowerCase();
    var exists = pattern.test(content);

  return exists;
}


  $("#3DSend").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const exists = validateText();

    if(exists) {

        alert("Слово найдено");

    }
    
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="validateText" value="" />
<button id="3DSend">Проверить</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя regex использует неверный синтаксис!

```
var pattern = /hello|hi/;
```

Если нужно чтоб отдельно слова определяло

```
var pattern = /(hello|hi)\b/;
```

Comment: так почти любое слово пишет, что оно есть в строке, хотя его нет. Например слово hellos, он найдет почему то. Ищется не по слову, а по символам както

Comment: Если надо, чтобы это слово отдельно было, то по концам добавить небуквенные символы можно.

Comment: @Leonid это какие? если я ставлю символы, то вообще не находит ничего. Или куда их надо?

Comment: @hellokitViki 
`var pattern = /(hello|hi)\b/;`

Comment: @DanRotaru, вначале тоже вроде надо добавить. `/(hello|hi)\b/i.test('Hiihello ioii, dude')` возвращает true.